# adding business logic to swiping with PageView or alike

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

how can I add conditions, popups etc to swiping?

I have a screen with 2 swiping areas (top and bottom) and a narrow middle input area. Now I want to implement some logic to the bottom swiping area. If the user starts swiping, the interface shall stop further swiping and show a countdown instead, after which swiping is possible (and similar interactions).

[image: wireframe]

Not sure, if this is possible (with a reasonable effort), however, currently I am not even having an idea how to tackle this. And I haven't found anything close here on stackoverflow except `onPageChanged` which does not work for my case (I guess). The tricky part, I guess, is that one should first see a brief swiping movement before popups etc are shown.

I guess, this not relevant for the solution, but I am generally using BloC for business logic.

Anyone with a solution or a path what to dive into?

Comment: Your question is very vague, as you don't provide any details of how you implemented anything.  How are you implementing the swiping?  If you use something like a PageView, then you can assign it a PageController, and if you do *that*, then you can assign a listener to the PageController, which will let you get notified of the scroll position, where you can do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. That is because I was unsure, which route to take. PageView was my solution in favor, but I didn't/don't know about the capabilities provided by the controller. But this is now a good starting point for me to find out. Thanks!